# How to get the full URL of the current page using PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

What is the "less code needed" way to get parameters from an URL query string which is formatted like the following?

**My current url**

```
www.mysite.com/category/subcategory/#myqueryhash
```

**I put this code**

```
$url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

It returns only `www.mysite.com/category/subcategory/`

**Output should be :**

```
www.mysite.com/category/subcategory/#myqueryhash
```

Comment: Is that the url you call or does the hashtag url is only shown on click on a "link"

Comment: You can use `window.location.hash` or `parse_url([your url])` to get the **#myqueryhash** from url.

Comment: output get only in php

Comment: @Manish Jesani You can't get the **#myqueryhash** from current URL using PHP, the only way is `window.location.hash` using javaScript.

Comment: The fragment part of the URL is never transmitted back to the server when a request is made, as it's intended to be an internal reference to the doc in the browser only. You *need* to use JS to extract it and pass it back to the server by hand.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can use this for HTTP request

```
<?php $current_url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>
```

You can use this for HTTPS request

```
<?php $current_url="https://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>
```

You can use this for HTTP/HTTPS request

```
<?php $current_url="//".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>
```

Comment: There's two ways, either you use javascript, where you can use "window.location.hash='myqueryhash';, or you bind your click event to an <a href="#myqueryhash">, and prevent default on click

Comment: @Priyank exactly, I told the same to Manish Jesani